# Using dash in folder names and linking for image

Tags: html, images, dash

I have image folders where I use dashes in the name for example: "images/01-12-2011/example.jpg"

When I insert this image into my html. Internet explorer(9) shows the image but Firefox and chrome doesn't show it. When I type it to the url: (blabla.com/images/01-12-2011/example.jpg) then i can see the image.

What could be the reason and the solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you viewed the HTML source in each browser or used something like Fiddler to see what is being requested?

Comment: yup, i have checked it and it seems correct. Can it be connected with the settings of Cpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely that the path to your image is broken, and the browser that's showing the image correctly has the file cached.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<img src="images/01-12-2011/example.jpg" />  
<img src="/images/01-12-2011/example.jpg" />
```

In the first line of code, the `img` tag tells the browser to look for the image in a sub-folder based off the current URL — this is referred to as a *relative* link.

In the second line of code, the `img` tag instructs the browser to start from the root directory of your site when looking for the image — this is referred to as an *absolute* link.

If you're seeing the images in one browser, but not others (and you're viewing them using the same URL) your primary browser may just have the files cached.

Without seeing a code sample of the page, it's difficult to determine what else might be the problem.

Comment: when i change the folder name 
from
"images/01-12-2011/example.jpg"
to
"images/01_12_2011/example.jpg"

images work and i can see in all browsers.

does it effect the seo results if use _ rather than - in the folder name. Or are there anything better?